# How to include a Pre-Defined text format for UITextField and replace the exact range while user key-in

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

How to include a textfield in a iOS project which has a pre-defined format mentioned, and while user key in, those format should be replaced with the typed content. Similarly when the content is deleted, again it should replace the format which exist in the particular range.

Note: Not as text field validator for input data but for visual representation while keeping in data.

Eg: Initial text of a phone field should be -> (###)-(#######)
    i.e: First group is for code and second for number.

while user typing data, at real time it should replace only the '#' and user should know how may placeholders is remaining. 
Also those hyphens and brackets should not be replaced nor deleted.

When user delete the text, it should again replace with the predefined format in the respective range.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for this is by using UITextFieldDelegate.
For sample project of the generic-format of text field, refer the given git-link 
https://github.com/iMitty8/iOSTextbox_Mandatory_Format

It is done in a generic way.
The following method is to create required format for text_field.

```
-(void)loadFormatForTextView {

    openFormat = @"(";
    closeFormat = @")";
    intermideateFormat = @"-";
    charFormat1 = @"#";
    //charFormat2 = nil;

    //(###)-(#######)
    NSArray *formatList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: openFormat,charFormat1,charFormat1,charFormat1,closeFormat,intermideateFormat,openFormat,charFormat1,charFormat1,charFormat1,charFormat1,charFormat1,charFormat1,charFormat1,closeFormat, nil ];

    phoneFormatString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    for (NSString *formatString in formatList) {
       [phoneFormatString appendString:formatString];
    }
    inputTest = [phoneFormatString copy];
    [_tbPhoneNo setText:phoneFormatString];
}
```

Implementing text field delegate to implement predefined format into UITextField

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:charFormat1];
    NSRange range = [textField.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        UITextPosition *cusorPosition = [textField positionFromPosition:[textField beginningOfDocument] offset:range.location];
        [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:cusorPosition toPosition:cusorPosition]];
    }
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if (range.location < phoneFormatString.length) {

        NSRange replacementRange = range;
        replacementRange.length = 1;
        NSRange nextStringRange;
        nextStringRange.length = 1;

        if([string isEqualToString:@""]) //Backspace
        {
            NSString *deleteString = [textField.text substringWithRange:replacementRange];
            if ([deleteString isEqualToString:openFormat] || [deleteString isEqualToString:closeFormat] || [deleteString isEqualToString:intermideateFormat]) {
            //
            }
            else
            {
                [textField setText:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:replacementRange withString:charFormat1]];
            }
            nextStringRange.location = range.location;
            NSString *nextString;

            for (nextString = [textField.text substringWithRange:nextStringRange]; ([nextString isEqualToString:intermideateFormat] || [nextString isEqualToString:openFormat] ) && nextStringRange.location != 0 ; )
            {
                nextStringRange.location = nextStringRange.location - 1;
                nextString = [textField.text substringWithRange:nextStringRange];
            }

            if (nextStringRange.location != 0) {

                UITextPosition *cusorPosition = [textField positionFromPosition:[textField beginningOfDocument] offset:nextStringRange.location];
                [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:cusorPosition toPosition:cusorPosition]];
            }
        }
        else if ([string isEqualToString:@" "]) //BlankSpace
        {
            //Do nothing//
        }
        else //Other
        {
           [textField setText:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:replacementRange withString:string]];
        nextStringRange.location = range.location + 1;

            NSString *nextString = [textField.text substringWithRange:nextStringRange];
            if ([nextString isEqualToString:openFormat] || [nextString isEqualToString:intermideateFormat] || [nextString isEqualToString:closeFormat]) { //Will redirect to first available blank

                NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:charFormat1];
                NSRange range = [textField.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];

                if (range.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    UITextPosition *cusorPosition = [textField positionFromPosition:[textField beginningOfDocument] offset:range.location];
                    [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:cusorPosition toPosition:cusorPosition]];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UITextPosition *cusorPosition = [textField positionFromPosition:[textField beginningOfDocument] offset:nextStringRange.location];
                [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:cusorPosition toPosition:cusorPosition]];
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField setText:phoneFormatString];

    NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:charFormat1];
    NSRange range = [textField.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        UITextPosition *cusorPosition = [textField positionFromPosition:[textField beginningOfDocument] offset:range.location];
        [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:cusorPosition toPosition:cusorPosition]];
    }

    return NO;
}
```